# ID Large brown/grey spider with light stripe along back

Tags: species-identification, arachnology

[image]

Giant spider on my door. Walked up to the door this morning and saw this beautiful lady waiting for me. I moved her to a tree so she can rest.

Comment: Can you please add the location?

Answer (score 3):

Looks like a [**wolf spider**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolf_spider).

- (though I can't [see the eyes](https://content.ces.ncsu.edu/fishing-spiders-and-wolf-spiders) to definitively rule out a [fishing spider](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dolomedes); though, fishing spiders don't [as often have a bright streak long their backs](https://a-z-animals.com/blog/fishing-spider-vs-wolf-spider-what-are-the-differences/) -- a characteristic your specimen shares more with wolf spiders).

Wolf spiders tend to be relatively large/robust, with strong bodies and legs. They are often brown or grey and can display striping on their legs.

Your image is not great and you lack sufficient detail (size, location,etc.) for a more certain ID. However, two examples of wolf spiders in the genus [***Tigrosa***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tigrosa) have similar characteristics to your image:

[*Tigrosa grandis*:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tigrosa_grandis)

[image]

<sup>Source: [bugguide.net](https://bugguide.net/node/view/361469); Credit: Andrew Williams (2009)</sup>

[*Tigrosa helluo*:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tigrosa_helluo)

[image]

<sup>Source: [bugguide.net](https://bugguide.net/node/view/144464); Credit: [Ashley Bradford](https://bugguide.net/user/view/7754) (2007)</sup>

If you provide more detail, I could try to update my post accordingly.